# Fill Missing value NAN with Mode is Not Working in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

All the values is the df are one hot encoded, ie 0 / 1

Tried

```
fill_mode = lambda col: col.fillna(col.mode())
df = df.apply(fill_mode, axis=0)
df.isnull().sum()
```

Got

```
id      0
1           0
2           2
3           0
```

Expect all Null or NAN is filled with Mode.

Answer (score 0):

`col.mode()` returns a series, not a single number. So `col.fillna(col.mode())` will try to align the index of `col.mode()` with `col` and most likely you won't get anything updated. Maybe you want to do:

```
fill_mode = lambda col: col.fillna(col.mode()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your `fill_mode` function

```
fill_mode = lambda col: col.fillna(col.mode().iloc[0])
df.apply(fill_mode, axis=0)
```

`mode` function return a series , `fillna` will match the index when received the series, however, in your case, we should remove the index match impacted.

Example

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'1':[np.nan,2,np.nan],'2':[1,1,np.nan]})

fill_mode = lambda col: col.fillna(col.mode())
print(df.apply(fill_mode, axis=0))
     1    2
0  2.0  1.0 # notice only the first item fill, since the out put of mode is index 0 with value 2
1  2.0  1.0
2  NaN  NaN 

df['1'].mode()
0    2.0
dtype: float64
```

In that case the df only fill the first value since the index matched.

We add the `.iloc` make it out put number , and will drop the index match with `fillna`

```
df['1'].mode().iloc[0]
2.0
```